# Why is the package found on Nuget not the latest version?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Why do I add packages such as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions to the .net core3.1 class library project, but only the 2.2 version can be found?

[image]

In the class library project of the same solution, the same version of these two packages cannot be found on nuget.

thanks

Comment: [There is no 3.1 version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions/) of this package

Comment: yep...2.2 is the latest version.

Comment: But in the mvc web project there is the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60

Comment: which mvc web project?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot/s of what you see that leads you to this conclusion?

Comment: @CaiusJard Please see the picture answered below

Answer (score 2):

TLDR - it is at the latest version.

Visit the nuget page of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions` here: :https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions/

You'll notice that the most recent version is indeed `2.2.0`

Why is that? Nuget packages reference each other with requirements. So a package with a version X.Y.Z might well require another library of S.T.U version, with the two version numbers being vastly different. Raising the version of one, doesn't mean that there will be a need to raise the other too.

In semantic versioning the numbers (usually) just indicate the following

X.Y.Z.

X. Major version. If this changes, then there are breaking changes in the update
Y. Minor version. If this changes, it is only additional functionality added, and you can update in the safety of knowing that your code won't break.
Z. Patch version. This is usually just bug fixes and performance enhancements.

Comment: While this is true in general, the case here is that this package is not needed for ASP.NET Core 3. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.NET Core 3+ this package is no longer produced. See
[Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0 - Remove obsolete package references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#remove-obsolete-package-references)

So you don't need it for ASP.NET Core 3 and later. Now this is enough:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

> large number of NuGet packages aren't produced for ASP.NET Core 3.0. Such package references should be removed from your project file.
>
> ...
>
> To see the full list of packages that are no longer produced ...
>
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.All
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.App
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.Routing
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Analyzers
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Api.Analyzers
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Abstractions
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets
> - Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities
> - Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand. When creating a new. Net core 3.1 MVC project, this library is included. These libraries are not required by. Net core 3.0?I don't get it.

Comment: Are those included for the template when selected .net core 3?

Comment: For .NET Core 2 those are needed, for .NET Core 3 there are not needed and not available. Same as for the Microsoft.AspNetCore package etc